# how to display all the records in the dataframe then based on filter replace it with the filtered dataframe using python and streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, streamlit

I have a streamlit application that read excel file and display the data as dataframe then allow user to do some filter in order to display the required data.

The problem is that i want to display by default all the dataframe then when user make some filter replace the exist datafarme with the filtered dataframe.

**The displayed result : empty datafarme**

**The expected result :  By default all record  then once the user make the filter it replace the existing dataframe with the filtered datafarme**

## code:

```
options_Users = df6['User'].unique().tolist()
selected_Users = st.sidebar.multiselect('Search By User',options_Users)

options_company = df6['company'].unique().tolist()
selected_company = st.sidebar.multiselect('Search By company',options_company)


if selected_Users:
     df6 = df6[df6["User"].isin(selected_Users)]
     st.markdown(
               f'<p class="header_title"> {str(df6.shape[0])} </p>',
               unsafe_allow_html=True,
               )

elif options_company:
     df6 = df6[df6["company"].isin(selected_company)]
     st.markdown(
               f'<p class="header_title"> {str(df6.shape[0])} </p>',
               unsafe_allow_html=True,
               )

else:
     st.markdown(
              f'<p class="header_title"> {str(df6.shape[0])} </p>',
              unsafe_allow_html=True,
          )
st.dataframe(df6.reset_index(drop = True).style.apply(highlight_rows, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace

```
elif options_company:
```

with

```
elif selected_company:
```

Then at the end use the following code below to display the whole dataframe if nothing is selected or show the selected frame if user or company is selected.

```
if selected_Users or selected_company:
    st.dataframe(df6.reset_index(drop = True))
else:
    st.dataframe(df)
```

#### Output

**1. In the beginning it shows the whole dataframe.**

[image]

**2. After selecting user 1.**

[image]

#### The full sample code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'User': ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'],
    'company': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df6 = df.copy()

options_Users = df6['User'].unique().tolist()
selected_Users = st.sidebar.multiselect('Search By User',options_Users)

options_company = df6['company'].unique().tolist()
selected_company = st.sidebar.multiselect('Search By company',options_company)


if selected_Users:
    df6 = df6[df6["User"].isin(selected_Users)]
    st.markdown(
               f'<p class="header_title"> {str(df6.shape[0])} </p>',
               unsafe_allow_html=True,
               )

elif selected_company:
    df6 = df6[df6["company"].isin(selected_company)]
    st.markdown(
               f'<p class="header_title"> {str(df6.shape[0])} </p>',
               unsafe_allow_html=True,
               )

else:
    st.markdown(
              f'<p class="header_title"> {str(df6.shape[0])} </p>',
              unsafe_allow_html=True,
          )
# st.dataframe(df6.reset_index(drop = True).style.apply(highlight_rows, axis=1))

if selected_Users or selected_company:
    st.dataframe(df6.reset_index(drop = True))
else:
    st.dataframe(df)
```